# When to use night/nighttime in the following context?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

> "How have you survived living here for nearly a year now if you don't like the hustle and bustle?"
>
> 1) "At night it's bearable."
>
> 2) "It's bearable at night."
>
> 3) "Night makes it bearable."
>
> 4) "At nighttime it's bearable."
>
> 5) "It's bearable at nighttime."
>
> 6) "Nighttime makes it bearable."

Which one of these responds do you native speakers find the most natural in this particular context? And which ones are not natural?

Comment: What do you think yourself? We ask questioners to do a little homework before posing their questions.

Comment: My guess is that I could use them all, but I have no idea if any of them would be natural. If I had to guess it would be #6, but I really don't know. Also, I can't figure out how natural "nighttime" is in general.

Comment: There are no factual answers to this question. 1. & 2. are identical in effect. 3. is nuanced. 4.5. & 6 add the suffix **time** without adding anything to the meaning. I would opt for 1.or 2. But that's merely an opinion.

Comment: Only #3 & #6 tell us that, because of the night-time, the place is bearable *all the time*. The other four answers might prompt the question "Yes - but how have you survived in the *daytime*?" I agree with writerfadbcl about #6.

Comment: You need to be more specific, if you don't want to just get random individual responses. The specific synonyms used could be different in each sentence too. You should focus on one particular thing.